# How to retrieve a mongodb document, then check if an array of objectIds contains a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following function

```
exports.createRequest = async (req, res) => {

  const currUser = await User.findById(req.user._id)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

  const friends = currUser.friends

  console.log(friends)

  const requestedId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)

  if (friends.includes(requestedId)) {

    return res.status(400).send('You\'re already friends')

  }

  ...

}
```

and the following model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  ...

  friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
})
```

Inside the database, the 'friends' field is an array of ObjectId's (as expected)

```
{
  friends: [ 000000483d6b4e132a0feb18, 5c62222b3d6b4e132a0feb17 ]
  _id: 5c62222b3d6b4e132a0feb16
}
```

But when I log the 'friends' constant (currUser.friends) into the console, I get this:

```
["000000483d6b4e132a0feb18","5c62222b3d6b4e132a0feb17"]
```

That means my includes() function isn't working because it's trying to find an ObjectId in an array of strings.

When I log currUser.friends[0] I get an ObjectId again...

```
000000483d6b4e132a0feb18
```

Does anyone know a better way of doing this? I've already tried casting req.params.id to a string to no avail.

I know I could include friends in the find query, but I have a lot of similar fields so it would be inefficient.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but it would seem that if  the constant "friends" is set to currUser.friends and your friends field is has the value of the generated id's mongoDB automatically assigns to every new document, what the console is logging is appropriate.

Comment: If I understand the question, you could try to pull the id from your request and run a ternary with indexOf(yourId) against the array of known id's..

Comment: Have tried to write the question a bit clearer - essentially the Type of the ids changes from ObjectId to string when I call currUser.friends, then back to ObjectId when I call currUser.friends[0], which means my code fails

Comment: Try it without the constant,  eg: if(currUser.friends.includes....

Comment: what is an output for `console.log(typeof currUser.friends[0])`;

Comment: It still evaluates to false when doing it without the constant. Output for `console.log(typeof currUser.friends[0])` is object